# summing functions handles in matlab

Tags: function, math, matlab

Hi
I am trying to sum two function handles, but it doesn't work.
for example:

> > y1=@(x)(x*x);
> >     y2=@(x)(x*x+3*x);
> >     y3=y1+y2

The error I receive is "??? Undefined function or method 'plus' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'."

This is just a small example, in reality I actually need to iteratively sum about 500 functions that are dependent on each other.

**EDIT**
The solution by Clement J. indeed works but I couldn't manage to generalize this into a loop and ran into a problem. I have the function `s=@(x,y,z)((1-exp(-x*y)-z)*exp(-x*y));` And I have a vector v that contains 536 data points and another vector w that also contains 536 data points. My goal is to sum up s(v(i),y,w(i)) for i=1...536 Thus getting one function in the variable y which is the sum of 536 functions. The syntax I tried in order to do this is:

```
sum=@(y)(s(v(1),y,z2(1))); 
for i=2:536 
  sum=@(y)(sum+s(v(i),y,z2(i))) 
end
```

Comment: I really know absolutely nothing about Matlab, but did you try writing `y3=@(x)( y1(x) + y2(x) )` ?

Comment: Non recursive solution: `mySum = @(y) sum( s(v,y,z) );` with variables `v` and `z` being in scope on function definition and function `sum` defined by MATLAB http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sum.html

Comment: If you find yourself needing to sum function handles like this, there is probably a better way of doing things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution proposed by Fyodor Soikin works.

```
>> y3=@(x)(y1(x) + y2(x))
y3 =
@(x) (y1 (x) + y2 (x))
```

If you want to do it on multiple functions you can use intermediate variables :

```
>> f1 = y1;
>> f2 = y2;
>> y3=@(x)(f1(x) + f2(x))
```

EDIT after the comment:
I'm not sure to understand the problem. Can you define your vectors v and w like that outside the function :

```
v = [5 4]; % your 536 data
w = [4 5];
y = 8;
s=@(y)((1-exp(-v*y)-w).*exp(-v*y))
s_sum = sum(s(y))
```

Note the dot in the multiplication to do it element-wise.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, this indeed works but I couldn't manage to generalize this into a loop and ran into a problem.

I have the function s=@(x,y,z)((1-exp(-x*y)-z)*exp(-x*y));
And I have a vector v that contains 536 data points and another vector w that also contains 536 data points.
My goal is to sum up s(v(i),y,w(i)) for i=1...536
Thus getting one function in the variable y which is the sum of 536 functions. The syntax I tried in order to do this is:
sum=@(y)(s(v(1),y,z2(1)));
for i=2:536
    sum=@(y)(sum+s(v(i),y,z2(i)))
end

Answer (score 2):

I think the most succinct solution is given in the comment by Mikhail. I'll flesh it out in more detail...

First, you will want to modify your [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html) `s` so that it can operate on vector inputs of the same size as well as scalar inputs ([as suggested by Clement J.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704664/summing-functions-handles-in-matlab/4704828#4704828)) by using [element-wise arithmetic operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) as follows:

```
s = @(x,y,z) (1-exp(-x.*y)-z).*exp(-x.*y);  %# Note the periods
```

Then, assuming that you have vectors `v` and `w` defined in the given workspace, you can create a new function `sy` that, for a given scalar value of `y`, will sum across `s` evaluated at each set of values in `v` and `w`:

```
sy = @(y) sum(s(v,y,w));
```

If you want to evaluate this function using an array of values for `y`, you can add a call to the function [ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) like so:

```
sy = @(y) arrayfun(@(yi) sum(s(v,yi,w)),y);
```

Note that the values for `v` and `w` that will be used in the function `sy` will be [fixed to what they were when the function was created](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html#f4-71621). In other words, changing `v` and `w` in the workspace will not change the values used by `sy`. Note also that I didn't name the new anonymous function `sum`, since there is already [a built-in function with that name](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sum.html).